# AMPScript Lookup From Child Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, sfmc-business-unit

I have a shared data extension that lives in our main business unit, but, is shared across all child business units. I am trying to do a lookup inside the child business unit in content builder. In content builder the lookup is validated but in Journey Builder it kicks me a validation error.

Here is the ampscript:

```
%%[
set @key = [id]
set @fname = Lookup ('shoppers', 'first_name', 'id', @key)
]%%
```

Here is the validation error:

> Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid An error occurred when
>   attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for
>   detail. Script Expression: Lookup ('shoppers', 'first_name', 'id',
>   @key) MemberID: 100012513 JobID: 0 The Data Extension name for a
>   Lookup function call is invalid. A Data Extension of this name does
>   not exist. Data Extension Name: shoppers Function Call: Lookup
>   ('shoppers', 'first_name', 'id', @key) Parameter Name:
>   DataExtensionName Parameter Ordinal: 1 Invalid Content: set @fname =
>   Lookup ('shoppers', 'first_name', 'id', @key) There is an error in
>   your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Error
>   1: Script SET Statement Invalid An error occurred when attempting to
>   resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script
>   Expression: Lookup ('shoppers', 'first_name', 'id', @key) MemberID:
>   100012513 JobID: 0 The Data Extension name for a Lookup function call
>   is invalid. A Data Extension of this name does not exist. Data
>   Extension Name: shoppers Function Call: Lookup ('shoppers',
>   'first_name', 'id', @key) Parameter Name: DataExtensionName Parameter
>   Ordinal: 1 Invalid Content: set @fname = Lookup ('shoppers',
>   'first_name', 'id', @key)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any DE that is in the shared folder is "owned" by the EID (Parent MID)  If you need to access it within a child BU you need to use the ENT. prefix.

You need to update your ampscript to the following:

```
%%[
set @key = [id]
set @fname = Lookup ('ent.shoppers', 'first_name', 'id', @key)
]%%
```